# how to calculate mean of multiple matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I have 2000 covariance matrices of size 27*27, I want to get the mean covariance matrix over all 2000 matrices. The result I want is one matrix of size 27x27 in which position [1,1] is the mean of position [1,1] of the given 27 matrices.
I could see from other posts that I should make an array and use apply function, but it does not work!

my codes:

```
a<-array(ml.1[c(1:2000)])
apply(a,c(1,2),mean)
```

I get this error message:
Error in if (d2 == 0L) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I would appreciate if anyone can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Please review [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, @eipi10 is right your're question is not reproducible. But the key here is in how you set up your array.

```
#Make some fake data 10 matrices 10x10
m <- lapply(1:10, function(x) matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 10))
#bind the matrices together
a <- do.call(cbind, m)
#recast the matrix into three dimensions
dim(a) <- c(10,10,10) 
#now apply should work
apply(a, c(1,2), mean)
```

Comment: Rather than reshaping the list, you can just add its elements: `Reduce(\`+\`, m) / length(m)`